# Am I allowed to ask what mod adds a feature in a game?

Tags: discussion

I downloaded a modpack for minecraft that adds some interesting features to my UI but I'm not sure which mod in the pack provides these features, I would ask, only I'm not sure if this form of question is on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not asking to add a feature - you already have it - you're just asking where it came from, and limiting the list of possibilities to what's contained in a certain mod pack.  It would be pretty analogous to asking something like "what does this icon mean?" for an unmodded game, which you shouldn't expect to be off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything particularly problematic with such a question, I'd say go ahead.